# Django locale/translations not showing

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

In typical Django development style, to form a complete picture of what to do, I am using a combination of

- The Django docs on localization (which actually only describes how to set up language files) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/localization/#
- This tutorial: http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/multi-language-support-in-a-django-project/
- An SO question: [django internationalization and translations issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639596/django-internationalization-and-translations-problem)

I have set up a fresh Django 1.4 site with a working "home" app and template with the following:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "hello" %}
```

My settings.py file follows the 2nd tutorial. Here are my middleware classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

and my views.py file looks like this:

```
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    c = Context({})
    return render_to_response('home/index.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What is really perplexing is how to edit the django.py files in my locale folder. The tutorial says "edit them," the Django docs don't mention them, and the SO question says to get rid of the `#, fuzzy` line.

here is what that file looks like (at the top)

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid "hello"
msgstr "Bonjour le Monde"
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-12-08 19:16+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After makemessages command you should have in django.po:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-12-08 19:16+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: templates/home/index.html:2
msgid "hello"
msgstr ""
```

Where do you store your templates and translations? In app or project directory?

Comment: In a project directory, so should that path start with the project name? (myproject/template...)

Comment: Tried this but I'm still not seeing the translation. Maybe the path is wrong? What should it be relative to?

Comment: I have no problem when locale directory is located in myproject.

Comment: So it would be safe to just move locale into that directory?

Comment: Tried moving locale into myproject but still no change.

Comment: I just added my middleware classes to my question. Is there something wrong there?

Comment: Hold up, I just put it in the second myproject folder and it works! Thank you!!