# Django Translation not working and showing trans tags

Tags: python, django, translation

I have a template I have created to add my project and I am using Django's translation module. I works fine with my already existing pages but on this one the translations are not rendered and instead it shows all the raw tags. I've compiled messages etc and still nothing. How do I fix this?

I've looked at the following questions but no dice:
[django - how to make translation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832709/django-how-to-make-translation-work)

[django internationalization and translations issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639596/django-internationalization-and-translations-problem)

[How to setup up Django translation in the correct way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/how-to-setup-up-django-translation-in-the-correct-way)

http://askbot.org/en/question/8948/weve-edited-djangopo-files-but-translations-do-not-work-why/

See picture: [image]

html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block bonos %}
<div class="container" >
 <div id='titleb' class="container">
  <h2 style= "color:black; align=center">MILINGUAL BONO</h2>
 </div>
 <div id='titleb' class="container">
  <h1 style= "color:black; align=center">MILINGUAL BONO</h1>
 </div>

 <div>
 <p>{% trans 'The Milingual Bono offers you more classes for much lesser. It saves you the hasslse of pasying each time you book a class, at the same time offering you the flexibilty of attending any Milingual class or event, anytime you want. Pick the 3 class bono if you would like to give it a try firt or book the <b>season bono</b> for unlimited access for 3 months.' %}
 </p>
 </div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- New set of columns, centered -->
        <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" >
              <div class="circle" style="background: #0045ab" ><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;"  >3</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">25€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">5€</span><br><br>
                    {% trans 'Ideal if you want to<br>
                  try out Milingual' %}</br>.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle" style="background: #58aeb4" ><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">6</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">39€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">21€</span><br><br>
                    {% trans 'Ideal if you want to<br>
                  try Milingual or have attended <br>
                  a couple of classes.' %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle"   style="background: #e8bf16"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">8</span><br> Credits
                </div>
                <div class="ribbon-wrapper-blue">
                  <div class="ribbon-blue">{% trans 'Most Popular' %}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="price">50€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">30€</span><br><br>
                    {% trans 'Ideal if you want to practice <br>
                  twice a week for a month' %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
<div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- New set of columns, centered -->
        <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" >
              <div class="circle"  style="background: #a7a5a7"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">10</span><br>Credits
              </div>
                <div id="price">64€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">36€</span><br><br>
                    {% trans 'Ideal if you want to make<br>
                  Milingual part of your routine' %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle"  style="background: #c6595b"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:60px;">12</span><br> Credits</div>
                <div id="price">79€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">41€</span><br><br>
                    {% trans 'Ideal for multiple classes per<be>
                  week.' %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center bonoint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
                <div class="circle2"   style="background: #b18358"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:50px;">SEASON</div>
                <div id="price">89€</div>
                <div id="savings">
                  {% trans 'You save' %} <span style="font-weight:bold">200€*</span><br><br>
                    {% trans 'Get unlimited accee to <br>
                  classes as well as paid events<br>
                  for no extra cost.' %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock bonos %}
```

Comment: Is this template included in another template ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django trans templatetag doesn't support multiple lines as Text

So use blocktrans tag in django that support multilines

```
 {% blocktrans %}
enter any code here that you want translation
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: these aren't multiline though. All of them a single lines

Comment: No, you have multiple lines. like: {% trans 'Ideal if you want to<br> try out Milingual' %} this is multiple line not in single line. cause of this in frontend that string showing as it is. try with blocktrans tag.

Comment: you pressed Enter after <br> of trans tag string. that cause this issue

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly now. I hadn't realized. That also explains why some of the translations worked, they weren't multi line translations.

Comment: In my case, the issue was that I had the `{% trans %}` tag before `{% load i18n %}`

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, please check your `settings.py` file if it includes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
)
...
LOCALE_PATHS = (BASE_DIR + '/locale',)
```

After that you should create a folder named as `locale` in your base directory, manually.

Then, you should make&compile messages, an instance below is for the German language and it uses `de` as a language code.

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=de
django-admin compilemessages
```

You can refer to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/) for more information about translation

Comment: this is already done. As I said above, other translations are working on the project but not this page